# Rspec manipulate upload size validator within a test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

On my `attachment` model I've got this validation:

```
validates_attachment_size :data, less_than: 8.megabyte, message: :data_file_size_error
```

It's doing everything I need, but in order to test it, right now I actually have to store a 9 MB file on my disk space. Since my application is rather huge I'd like to avoid doing this.

So my thoughts were - can I manipulate the validation method itself, but just for the test. Let's say, set the validation inside of the `context` block size to 5 KB, try to upload a 6 KB file and then set it back to normal?

(For the record: the process is rather cumbersome - I am creating an ingoing email, then adding a file to it, then trying to import this file. This is why I'd like to keep the file rather small. Another option I tried was to `stub` the filesize, but in the integration test Rspec would still access the real size, thus, resulting in failing tests)

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot easily stub the filesize, because it's checked only once, during class load. There are quite a few ways you can deal with this problem though:

1. You can keep a 9MB file in some directory that's added to `.gitignore`, e.g. `tmp/testfiles` and when running spec you can generate this file if it's not present. This way you'll generate it only once, so future tests will be faster (no need to generate it every time) and you won't keep it in your repository
2. You can make `less_than` option dynamic, i.e. do something like `less_than: -> { maximum_file_size }` and then define a method `def self.maximum_file_size; 8.megabyte; end`. Then you should be able to stub this easily, because the maximum size is determined on every upload. The downside is that you add the dynamic option just for the testing purpose, but it affects your production code.
3. You can just write a unit test that will verify that the correct size is called. `it { should validate_attachment_size(:image).less_than(5.megabytes) }`. Then you don't perform actual file upload, but as long as you trust your library, this test should be enough. (the code assumes that you use Paperclip, it might look different for other libraries).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think this solution is quite elegant and it's what I ended up using:

```
validator = Profile::Attachment._validators[:data].find{|validator| validator.options[:less_than]}
validator.stubs(:options).returns({less_than: 2500, message: :data_file_size_error}) # 2500 Bytes are ~ 2,44 KB
```

with this code I can upload a 3KB file and it will result is this validation failing.